# GA4 Configuration Tag Firing Status "Failed"

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have 2 environments set up in GTM (Live and UAT) using the Constant Variable and Lookup Table for GA4 Config Tag implementation. The live environment works fine, but the UAT environment does not. Tag Assistant Legacy shows successful implementation of GTM, but firing status is "Failed". I do not have any add blockers. There is no HTML that would have the same ID (_ga).

Does anyone have experience with this type of example?

Comment: see the answer here: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/137534/google-tag-manager-ua-tag-not-firing-and-having-issues-with-gtm-tag-assistant/137569#137569 if it's not enough, update your question with screenshots from debugging in the preview.